# A Number State of Light through a dielectric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

If a number state |1> picks up a factor of  $e^{-i\phi}$ on going through a certain medium, what factor will a number state |N> pick up? Will it be $e^{-iN\phi}$ or $e^{-i\phi}$ or something else? And what is the justification? Thanks.

Comment: this would need the details of the system

Comment: Keep in mind that a global phase factor does not change a state. So you can safely ignore it. Phase is a relative concept.

Comment: @flippiefanus These are typically not global phases - unless you send a Fock state through the BS.  The question here really seems to ask for the action on a basis.  E.g., these phases are relevant to understand what happens to coherent states.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a linear optical medium - which is typically the case up to good accuracy - it will act as $a^\dagger\to e^{-i\phi} a^\dagger$ on the creation operators (i.e. in Heisenberg picture). Thus, it acts as
$$
|n\rangle =\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^\dagger)^n|0\rangle \ \to\ 
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(e^{-i\phi}a^\dagger)^n|0\rangle=e^{-in\phi}|n\rangle\ .
$$